Spring Boot throwing 401 Unauthorized on POST request
I am working on a spring-boot web app and have configured Spring Security with JWT. My issue is that when I make a POST request in Postman, I receive a 401 Unauthorized error. However, when I make a GET request, it returns data with a 200 status. This seems to be a common issue; I've checked different threads on stackoverflow, and most suggest disabling CSRF in the security config. I've already done this, but it’s still not working.
Request "/courses/**" with permitAll(), should be accessible without authentication.
SecurityConfig.java
@Configuration 
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

private final CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
private final JwtAuthEntryPoint jwtAuthEntryPoint;

@Bean
public AuthTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter(){
    return new AuthTokenFilter();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
    return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
    var authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authProvider;
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)  // Disable CSRF for stateless APIs
            .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthEntryPoint))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth->
                            auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/api/roles/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/api/users/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/courses/**").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            );
    http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}

}

Post Method
    @PostMapping("/add-course")
public ResponseEntity<?> addCourse(@RequestBody Course course){
    try{
        System.out.println("Course body: " + course);
        Course theCourse = courseService.addNewCourse(course);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(theCourse);
    }catch (Exception e){
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
    }
}

Postman API call Image
POSTMAN post request

Just a guess, but try removing the leading slash from "/add-course" in the PostMapping

Consider testing the POST request by temporarily permitting all requests
(.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll())

to see if the problem persists. This can help identify if the issue is specific to your /courses/** configuration.

Learn to use markdown to format your posts.

This suggestion worked, I also tried suggestion provided by Vijay and also made some changes in the code. POST request is working as expected now. Thanks!

I would like to go with chained configuration instead of separate configuration.
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)  // Disable CSRF for stateless APIs
            .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthEntryPoint))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth->
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/api/roles/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/api/users/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/courses/**").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            ).build();
}

It ensures that the configuration is applied in a single fluent chain and avoids issues with multiple http.build() calls.

Thanks for the response.
I made some changes in the code, I used a courseDto to save the course instead of directly passing the Course entity and went with the suggestion provided by Vijay Kumar to go with the chained configuration instead of separate configuration.
POST request is working as expected now. Check the attached image below.
POSTMAN post method

You wrote (in your answer): I made some changes in the code. Maybe you could [edit] your answer and post those changes as they may help others who are experiencing similar problems.

@Abra i think, other changes are not directly related to the original question.

UPDATE
I encountered the same issue again with an update request (PUT method) where I was getting a 401 Unauthorized error. I tried the suggestion provided by Kunal and Abra, I tested the PUT request by temporarily permitting all requests and it worked. Later, I removed the line auth.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll() and uncommented the specific request matchers. After this, I tried the PUT request again, and it worked without hitting the 401 error.
I realized that for the first POST and PUT requests, we need to temporarily permit all requests by adding the line auth.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll(). Once these requests work, we can remove this line, uncomment the specific request matchers, and all subsequent requests will work without any 401 errors.
 auth.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
 //auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
 //.requestMatchers("/api/roles/**").permitAll()
 //.requestMatchers("/api/users/**").permitAll()
 //.requestMatchers("/courses/**").permitAll()
 //.anyRequest().authenticated()

FilterChain
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)  // Disable CSRF for stateless APIs
            .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthEntryPoint))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth-> //  auth.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                            auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/api/roles/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/api/users/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/courses/**").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            ).build();
}


How will you allow and disallow over server?

Could you please post your filterChain fucntion?

You're right, I am not sure why it's happening. I have added the filterChain function in the answer.
